# Server (IO) Error - из-за чего возникает?

Tags: javascript

У моего журналиста на одном из сайтов часто возникает ошибка *Server (IO) Error*, хотелось бы узнать, почему она возникает.

Есть подозрения на эти части кода .js файлов:

```
SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR = {
    HTTP_ERROR                      : -200,
    MISSING_UPLOAD_URL              : -210,
    **IO_ERROR                      : -220,**
    SECURITY_ERROR                  : -230,
    UPLOAD_LIMIT_EXCEEDED           : -240,
    UPLOAD_FAILED                   : -250,
    SPECIFIED_FILE_ID_NOT_FOUND     : -260,
    FILE_VALIDATION_FAILED          : -270,
    FILE_CANCELLED                  : -280,
    UPLOAD_STOPPED                  : -290
};
```

и

```
case SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR.IO_ERROR:c.setStatus("Server (IO) Error");this.debug("Error Code: IO Error, File name: "+a.name+", Message: "+b);break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решается очень просто - загрузка файлов через IE.